# How to have a function run a callback in VB.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, callback

I'm afraid I have been Googling this, but can't find an answer that I understand, or can use.

In Javascript, you can run a function and set a callback function which it calls after the first function has run:

```
function doThis(callBack){
    // do things
    // do things
    if(callBack){
         callBack();
    }
}
```

Call this by: `doThis(function () { alert("done") });`

So after it's finished doing things it calls an alert to tell you it's done.

But how do you do the same server-side in VB.NET?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just create a method that takes an [`Action` delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx) as parameter:

```
Sub DoThis(callback as Action)

    'do this
    'do that

    If Not callback Is Nothing Then
        callback()
    End If

End Sub
```

and you can call it like

```
DoThis(Sub() Console.WriteLine("via callback!"))
```

Comment: Brilliant, so simple yet I couldnt find how to do it! :-)